# There is a way in the copy activity (Data Factory) to ingest an api with XML return that returns with multiple root elements

Tags: xml, azure, web-services, azure-data-factory

I need to ingest a web service with XML return using the data factory. But the return of this web service does not have a root element.

**Example:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<resposta>
   <identificacao>
        <id>215874</id>
   </identificacao>
    <carga>
        <valor>525.922,27</valor>
        <descricao>Confeccoes</descricao>
        <operacao>Distribuicao</operacao>
    </carga>
</resposta>
<resposta>
    <identificacao>
        <id>258741</id>
    </identificacao>
    <carga>
        <valor>200.235,01</valor>
        <descricao>Alimento</descricao>
        <operacao>Distribuicao</operacao>
    </carga>
</resposta>
```

When using a data factory `copy activity` with the `return` of the web service like this, I'm getting this message:

```
Error code 21374

Details
Input XML file 'filename' is invalid with parsing error 'There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 3452.'. There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 3452. Activity ID: activity_id
```

My settings in the `copy activity` in the source tab are these:

```json
 {
     "name": "Copy data",
     "type": "Copy",
     "dependsOn": [],
     "policy": {
                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                "retry": 3,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 45,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
               },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                   "source": {
                      "type": "XmlSource",
                          "storeSettings": {
                               "type": "HttpReadSettings",
                               "maxConcurrentConnections": 1,
                               "requestMethod": "POST",
                               "requestBody": {
                               "value": "@{replace(\n    replace(\nstring('<request><metodo>OBTER_POSICOES_DET</metodo><data_ini>dataini</data_ini><data_fin>datafin</data_fin></request>'),\n'dataini', variables('data_ini')),\n'datafin', variables('data_fin'))}\n",
                               "type": "Expression"
                          },
                          "requestTimeout": "00:01:40"
                        },
                          "formatSettings": {
                               "type": "XmlReadSettings",
                               "validationMode": "none",
                               "detectDataType": true,
                               "namespaces": true
                         }
},...
```

**I am currently doing the following.**

Creating a list with the Ids, passing the notebook output to ForEach and for each Id executing a request. Inside **ForEach** we have the copy activity

**Pros**: It solves my problem so I can get all the "<resposta>"

**Con**: The cost of time and money to perform the intake every day is high.

What I expect is to be able to run copy data and return "<resposta>" from multiple Ids.

Comment: Multiple roots are by definition invalid XML.  You may need to download everything and then separate them for processing.  What is producing the XML? Can it be configured to wrap everything in a top-level root?

Comment: @JimGarisson the XML is the result of an external web service. Really the XML this way is invalid, but I have no way to correct it. I would like to know if it would be possible to download all the XMLs at once instead of a request per response.

Comment: You would need to write code to (1) download the entire XML response and save it to a buffer (memory or disk), (2) split it into valid XML chunks, and (3) feed the chunks to the data factory.  I know nothing about Azure so I can't tell you if step 3 is even possible.  Assuming it is, it should be relatively easy to do steps 1 and 2.   Note you wouldn't be able to use an XML parser on the entire stream, it would have to be plain Java looking for `<reposta>` and `</reposta>`.

Comment: @JimGarisson had already implemented points (1) and (2) in python. But that wouldn't solve it because the company's architecture is very "stuck" and because of that and the cost, the ideal would be to deal with this problem directly in the data factory

Answer (score 0):

As per [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#rest-as-source), As REST connector only support response in JSON.

REST does not support XML response.

You can try approach suggested by [JimGarisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison) in comments.

[image]